# Resume data is always nil when invoking cancelByProducingResumeData:

Tags: ios, ios7

I am trying to access the `resumeData` of a downloading file in when the application is terminated. I've tried calling the method from both `willEnterBackground` and `willTerminate` in the `appDelegate`.

I can access the `resumeData` value from the view class, but the problem is that when invoking this method, the `downloadSession` is automatically closed.

Comment: In `didEnterBackground`, you have "5 seconds" to finish your things, maybe that's related. source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `cancelByResumingData:` , it will produce the resumeData and just after that it will call the `URLSessionTask-didCompleteWithError`.
There we set a flag for detecting where the app is paused or not and we can store the `resumeData` without cancelling the download.

This can be resumed later when the app is re-launched as follows:

```
self.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithResumeData: objFile.resumeData];
[self.downloadTask resume];

// Here objFile is an object stored in core data
```